# Failure occurred while uploading to jfrog artifactory

Tags: github-actions, jfrog-cli

I am using jfrog cli in github actions to upload a binary to jfrog generic repository. Ping to the artifactory server gives OK. But Uploads fails by giving 401.

Here is the action

```
  - name: Configuring artifactory
    uses: "jfrog/setup-jfrog-cli@v2"
  - name: Pushing artifactory
    env: 
      APIKEY: ${{secrets.RT_APIKEY}}
    run: |
      jf c add --url https://artifactory.xxxxxx.ae:443 --user amal45 --password "$APIKEY"
      jf rt ping
      cd workspace
      sudo touch newfile.txt
      jf rt u newfile.txt github_actions_testing
```

Error

> 12:18:31 [Info] [Thread 2] Uploading artifact: newfile.txt

> 12:18:32 [Warn] [Thread 2] (Attempt 1) - Failure occurred while uploading to https://artifactory.xxxxxx.tii.ae:443/artifactory/github_actions_testing/newfile.txt;build.name=Check+default+branch;build.number=39;build.timestamp=1653481111573;
> vcs.revision=68f122d5297bfbd425125bf2d60a58f32f96356f;vcs.url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Famalx%2Fxxxx_build.git;vcs.branch=development: Server response: 401

> 12:18:33 [Warn] [Thread 2] (Attempt 2) - Failure occurred while uploading to https://artifactory.xxxxxxx.ae:443/artifactory/github_actions_testing/newfile.txt;build.name=Check+default+branch;build.number=39;build.timestamp=1653481111573;vcs.revision=68f122d5297bfbd425125bf2d60a58f32f96356f;vcs.url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Famalx-%2Fxxxxxx_build.git;vcs.branch=development: Server response: 401

> 12:18:33 [Warn] [Thread 2] (Attempt 3) - Failure occurred while uploading to https://artifactory.xxxxxx.ae:443/artifactory/github_actions_testing/newfile.txt;build.name=Check+default+branch;build.number=39;build.timestamp=1653481111573;vcs.revision=68f122d5297bfbd425125bf2d60a58f32f96356f;vcs.url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Famalx%2Fxxxxx_build.git;vcs.branch=development: Server response: 401

> 12:18:34 [Warn] [Thread 2] (Attempt 4) - Failure occurred while uploading to https://artifactory.xxxx.ae:443/artifactory/github_actions_testing/newfile.txt;build.name=Check+default+branch;build.number=39;build.timestamp=1653481111573;vcs.revision=68f122d5297bfbd425125bf2d60a58f32f96356f;vcs.url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Famalx%2Fxxxxx_build.git;vcs.branch=development:
> Server response: 401

> {
> "status": "failure",
> "totals": {
> "success": 0,
> "failure": 0
> }
> }

> 12:18:34 [Info] [Thread 2]  executor timeout after 3 attempts with 0 milliseconds wait intervals

> Error: 4 [Error] Server response: 401

> Error: 4 [Error] Failed uploading 1 artifacts.

> Error: 4 [Error] Server response: 401

> Error: 4 [Error] upload finished with errors, Please review the logs

> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

what may be the cause of this error?

Comment: please copy/paste relevant YAML and error messages. screenshots make it hard for people with the same problem to find your question.

Comment: I couldn't this issue to reproduce locally for me. Which Artifactory version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Problem here was the usage of ${{secrets.RT_APIKEY}}. This workflow here in the question was a **called** workflow. I was not passing the value RT_APIKEY from **caller** workflow using `with:`